# Where can I find the kernel logs?

Tags: 10.04, kernel

Anybody know the best way to write/read/commit/document/upload errors in the kernel log in Ubuntu 10.04?

Are there a tool suitable for this type of job in the UBuntu Software repositories?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I guess you can also use gnome's application:

System -> Administration -> Log File Viewer

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 21):

For those with server/no monitor access you can access the logs using [`tail`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/maverick/en/man1/tail.1posix.html)

```
tail -f /var/log/kern.log
```

Answer (score 2):

dmesg command can also be used to display the kernel log. It can be used as follows.

```
dmesg -k -w
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a nice graphical *viewer* for the kernel logs by the people at KDE.

**[KSystemLog [image]](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/ksystemlog)**

[image: KSystemLog Screenshot]